# How do I prevent the .dccache file from being created?

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode keeps adding a file named `.dccache`. How can I prevent this?

It messes up the github diffs and I keep on having to add `.dccache` to the `.gitignore` for several different projects.

I can't find anything about why .dccache is being created in the first place

[image: 5 results for ".dccache" "vscode"]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It can also be created by the [Snyk](https://snyk.io/) extension.

Comment: Yes Maybe it's from Snyk extension.  When i started using Snyk i noticed after that this file started generating.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same file, I believe this is being created from DeepCode: https://www.deepcode.ai/

This is a code analysis tool to try to find issues.  Check if you installed the DeepCode extension in VSCode if you want to get rid of this file, otherwise ignoring it should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The DeepCode plugins or the CLI is using this file to create a cache for the source code bundles send to the analysis engine. Without this cache, the collection and upload would be very time-consuming.
As it only serves as a caching mechanism, you can exclude it from git uploads and ignore it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Snyk extention has a Help&Feedback tab, on the FAQ there is a 'Add custom .dcignore file to your workspace'.

Sometimes git ignore doesn't work for me

I used this file: https://github.com/DeepCodeAI/dcignore/blob/master/full.dcignore.js
just create .dcignore and copy all contents to that. I manually add .dccache and .dcignore just in case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and when I disabled `Snyk` extension on VS code editor is disappeared, if you don't have `Snyk` installed and still have `.dccache` appearing every now and them, just keep an eye on the other extensions, disable each one at a time and see which one is creating the `.dccache` file